# Multiple updates to multiple tables in one query with only one condition

Tags: mysql

I would like transform those queries above into a single one in MySQL:

```
UPDATE ps_stock_available 
SET    `quantity` = 0 
WHERE  id_product IN (SELECT id_product 
                      FROM   ps_product_shop 
                      WHERE  `date_upd` < Now() - INTERVAL 48 hour);


UPDATE ps_product_lang 
SET    `available_later` = 
'Sobre Pedido: Entrega de 4 a 6 semanas --Sujeto a disponibilidad--' 
WHERE  id_product IN (SELECT id_product 
                      FROM   ps_product_shop 
                      WHERE  `date_upd` < Now() - INTERVAL 48 hour);


UPDATE ps_warehouse_product_location 
SET    `id_warehouse` = 3 
WHERE  id_product IN (SELECT id_product 
                      FROM   ps_product_shop 
                      WHERE  `date_upd` < Now() - INTERVAL 48 hour);


UPDATE ps_stock_available 
SET    `out_of_stock` = 2 
WHERE  id_product IN (SELECT id_product 
                      FROM   ps_product_shop 
                      WHERE  `date_upd` < Now() - INTERVAL 48 hour);
```

What is the rigth way to do these 4 updates in one single efficient query?

Comment: That is the right way.  There's no way you can update multiple tables using 1 statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are updating different tables, I don't think there is a way to do that with a single query.

If you were updating a single table, you could bundle all the values you wanted to insert into a single query.

What you could to do to save time is avoid doing the same subquery 4 times by saving the array of `id_product` as `id_products` and then running the 4 queries with that array.